# How to write file to sd-card? (Android) No errors, but nothing written

Tags: java, android, storage, external

I'm new to developing android apps. And already overchallenged with my first project.  My app should be able to save a list of `EditText` fields to a text file by clicking a "save"-Button.
But I got no success to write a file to my SD-card.

My code:
(function in `MainActivity.java` called by the button)

```
public void saveData(View view){
        try{
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // to this path add a new directory path
        File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myapp/");
        // create this directory if not already created
        dir.mkdir();

        // create the file in which we will write the contents

        File file = new File(dir, "datei.txt");


        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        String data = "some string";
        os.write(data.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("com.sarbot.FitLogAlpha", "Cant find Data.");
        }
    }
```

With Google I found another way:

```
public void saveData3(View view){
    FileWriter fWriter;
    File sdCardFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/datafile.txt");
    Log.d("TAG", sdCardFile.getPath()); //<-- check the log to make sure the path is correct.
    try{
         fWriter = new FileWriter(sdCardFile, true);
         fWriter.write("CONTENT CONTENT UND SO");
         fWriter.flush();
         fWriter.close();
     }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

In my `manifest.xml` I set the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And the function from developer guide returns me True -> SD-card is writable.

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the `res/layout/activity_main.xml` are some `TextViews` and `EditText` and a save button with `android:onClick="saveData"` argument. The function is called. The SD-card is writable. And no IO errors. But after pressing the button (without error) there is still no new file on my SD-card. I already tried to create the file manually and just append but nothing changed. I tried some other function with `BufferedWriter` too .. but no success.

I'm running my Sony Xperia E with USB-Debug mode. Unmount and mounted the SD-card on my PC but cant find the file. Maybe it is only visible for the phone? It doesn't exist? I don't know what to do because I get no errors. I need the content of this file on my computer for calculations.

:EDIT:
The problem was not in the code.. just in the place I looked up. The externalStorage -> sdCard seems to be the internal and the removable sdcard is the -> ext_card.

Comment: os.flush() -  method flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

Comment: @Glod Glodson where do you look for the file? where do you search for that? can you tell me the address ?

Comment: I looked on my removable sd-card on my pc. I already found the file. The getExternalDirectory() seems to be the internal sdcard. confusing. So sdcard=externalstorage but inside the phone, ext_card = removable "rly external" sd-card. If I figure out how i can acces to the ext_card this is solved. Perfect would be a way to export the file via email, dropbox or something but this should be another step I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line,

```
 File file = new File(dir, "datei.txt");
```

Add this code

```
 if ( !file.exists() )
 {
      file.createNewFile();         // This line will create new blank line.
 }
```

Comment: i added this as well but still no changes. Is it possible that the file exists but i just don't see them with usb-storage mode on my pc?

Comment: May be possible, do one thing, remove the phone from usb port and then check the file. Also do one thing,  remove the old app, and re-run the project. Sometimes changes doesnt occurs.

Comment: I will install a filebrowser on my phone to check it there. The other I have already done.

Comment: thats it.. i used a file browser on my phone and found the file (and some from old tries) :) ok so the code work. I just didn't understand the Android file management. the sdcard/ folder is my internal storage or not the sdcard i can remove. this is ext_card. Confusing. But how  get the Path of my EXTERNAL sdcard if getExternalDirectory() returns the internal sd-card.

Answer (score 0):

`os.flush()` is missing in your code. Add this snippet before `os.close()`

Comment: i added os.flush() after the os.write() but still nothing changed